# How to use a bidirectional RNN layer in tensorflow ?

Tags: tensorflow

When we add a bidirectional RNN layer I can understand that we have to concatenate hidden states. If we use bidirectional RNN layer in encoder decoder model do we have to train the bidirectional RNN layer separately ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. To quote from the abstract of [*Bidirectional Recurrent Neural Networks*](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/4b80/89bc9b49f84de43acc2eb8900035f7d492b2.pdf) by Schuster and Paliwal:

> The BRNN can be trained without the limitation of using input information just
>   up to a preset future frame. This is accomplished by training it
>   **simultaneously** in positive and negative time direction.

I guess you are talking about [`tf.nn.static_bidirectional_rnn`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/static_bidirectional_rnn).